# How to enable/disable X inputs when certain checkbox (radio button) is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem and not sure how should I approach it.

I have a page like the next one:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″ />    
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">          
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<br><br>

<form style="margin-bottom: 20px; border:4px solid black;background-color:#bdd6ee" id="My-Form"  class="col-md-11 container" method="POST" action="../Views/logout.php">
    <br>
    <span style="color: #dc3545;" class="fa fa-address-card fa-2x"></span></p>
    <div style=" padding: 15px; border: 2px solid black; background-color:white">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-4" hidden>
                <input type="text" name="Academico" class="form-control" value="Academico" readonly>
            </div>
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center" ><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD" name="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" id="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" style="margin-left: 5px; position: unset"> </td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"><b>CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Carrera</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="CARRERA" id="CARRERA_0" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Universidad</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="UNIVERSIDAD" id="UNIVERSIDAD_0" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>                
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>¿Por qué?</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="PORQUE" id="PORQUE_0" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-row">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center" ><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA" name="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" id="MOTIVO_CAMBIO_1" style="margin-left: 5px; position: unset"> </td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"><b>CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Universidad</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="UNIVERSIDAD" id="UNIVERSIDAD_1" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>                
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>¿Por qué?</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="PORQUE" id="PORQUE_1" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-row">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center" ><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="CAMBIO DE CARRERA, MISMA UNIVERSIDAD" name="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" id="MOTIVO_CAMBIO_2" style="margin-left: 5px; position: unset"> </td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"><b>CAMBIO DE CARRERA, MISMA UNIVERSIDAD</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Carrera</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="CARRERA" id="CARRERA_1"size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>                
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>¿Por qué?</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="PORQUE" id="PORQUE_2" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div  class="col text-center">
            <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" type="submit">Ninguna de las anteriores</button>
        </div>  
    </div><br>
</form>

<div  class="col text-center">
    <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" type="submit" form="My-Form" >Enviar</button>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

[Picture of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeACU.png)

So, as you can see, I have three checkboxes (CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD, CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA and CAMBIO DE CARRERA, MISMA UNIVERSIDAD).

When I click for example in "CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD", the three options next to it are going to get enable ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjqZ1.png)), and the other ones are going to be disabled..If for some reason, I wanted to click on "CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA", then, the 2 options next to it are going to get enable and the other ones disabled.

I have the next code where I can do what I want but only with the first checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#MOTIVO_CAMBIO").on('change', function(){
        var isWorking = $("#MOTIVO_CAMBIO").val();
        if(isWorking === "CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD"){
            $("#CARRERA_0").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#UNIVERSIDAD_0").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#PORQUE_0").prop("disabled", false);
        }else if(isWorking === "CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA"){
            $("#UNIVERSIDAD_1").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#PORQUE_1").prop("disabled", false);
        }else if(isWorking === "CAMBIO DE CARRERA, MISMA UNIVERSIDAD"){
            $("#CARRERA_1").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#PORQUE_2").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
        
});
```

So, basically, what I'm trying to do is that when I click in one of the three options mentioned above, the options right next to it are going to get enable, but I'm not sure how to approach this. I know that I'm doing wrong in my Javascript/jQuery because if I want to add another option, then I'm going to be adding another "else if" and so on, so I know that's the wrong approach.

Any hint on how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add event listeners for all your radio buttons, as following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="MOTIVO_CAMBIO"]');

    function changeHandler(event) {
       if ( this.value === 'CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD' ) {
         $("#CARRERA_0").prop("disabled", false);
         $("#UNIVERSIDAD_0").prop("disabled", false);
         $("#PORQUE_0").prop("disabled", false);


         $("#UNIVERSIDAD_1").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#PORQUE_1").prop("disabled", true);

         $("#CARRERA_1").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#PORQUE_2").prop("disabled", true);


       } else if ( this.value ==='CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA' ) {
         $("#UNIVERSIDAD_1").prop("disabled", false);
         $("#PORQUE_1").prop("disabled", false);

         $("#CARRERA_0").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#UNIVERSIDAD_0").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#PORQUE_0").prop("disabled", true);

         $("#CARRERA_1").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#PORQUE_2").prop("disabled", true);


       }  else if (this.value === 'CAMBIO DE CARRERA, MISMA UNIVERSIDAD'){
         $("#CARRERA_1").prop("disabled", false);
         $("#PORQUE_2").prop("disabled", false);

         $("#CARRERA_0").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#UNIVERSIDAD_0").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#PORQUE_0").prop("disabled", true);

         $("#UNIVERSIDAD_1").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#PORQUE_1").prop("disabled", true);


       }
    }

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
       radio.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the if/else you can use the same html and changed js code below. Basically by attaching a click event disable all text inputs and find the current elements index. With that index find parent element (.form-row). After that is just enable that you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        let index = $("input[type='radio']").index($(this))
        $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', true)
        $('.form-row:eq('+index+') input[type="text"]').removeAttr('disabled')
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">          
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form style="margin-bottom: 20px; border:4px solid black;background-color:#bdd6ee" id="My-Form"  class="col-md-11 container" method="POST" action="../Views/logout.php">
    <br>
    <span style="color: #dc3545;" class="fa fa-address-card fa-2x"></span></p>
    <div style=" padding: 15px; border: 2px solid black; background-color:white">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-4" hidden>
                <input type="text" name="Academico" class="form-control" value="Academico" readonly>
            </div>
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr class="disabled_rows">
                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center" ><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD" name="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" id="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" style="margin-left: 5px; position: unset"> </td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"><b>CAMBIO DE CARRERA Y DE UNIVERSIDAD</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Carrera</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="CARRERA" id="CARRERA_0" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Universidad</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="UNIVERSIDAD" id="UNIVERSIDAD_0" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>                
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>¿Por qué?</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="PORQUE" id="PORQUE_0" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-row">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center" ><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA" name="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" id="MOTIVO_CAMBIO_1" style="margin-left: 5px; position: unset"> </td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"><b>CAMBIO DE UNIVERSIDAD, MISMA CARRERA</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Universidad</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="UNIVERSIDAD" id="UNIVERSIDAD_1" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>                
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>¿Por qué?</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="PORQUE" id="PORQUE_1" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-row">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center" ><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="CAMBIO DE CARRERA, MISMA UNIVERSIDAD" name="MOTIVO_CAMBIO" id="MOTIVO_CAMBIO_2" style="margin-left: 5px; position: unset"> </td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"><b>CAMBIO DE CARRERA, MISMA UNIVERSIDAD</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>Carrera</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="CARRERA" id="CARRERA_1"size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 1%"></td>                
                    <td style="width: 15%; color: #2e75b5"></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%; color: #2e75b5; text-align: right"><b>¿Por qué?</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"><input class="form-check-input" type="text" style="margin-left: 10px; position: unset;" name="PORQUE" id="PORQUE_2" size="50" disabled> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div  class="col text-center">
            <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" type="submit">Ninguna de las anteriores</button>
        </div>  
    </div><br>
</form>

<div  class="col text-center">
    <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" type="submit" form="My-Form" >Enviar</button>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```